# Почему не работает поиск по значению атрибута XPATH?

Tags: java, xml

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document d=db.parse("products.xml");
    Element element=d.getDocumentElement();
    String h=scn.nextLine();
    XPath xp=XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr2 = xp.compile(h);
    NodeList nl2=(NodeList)xp.compile("//products/child::*").evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for(int i=0; i<nl2.getLength(); i++){
    System.out.println(nl2.item(i).getLocalName());
    System.out.println(nl2.item(i).getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue());
    if(h.equals(nl2.item(i).getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue())){
        Element element3 = (Element) xp.evaluate(String.format("//*[@%s='%s']", nl2.item(i).getAttributes(), nl2.item(i).getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue() ), d, XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(element3.getNodeName());
        System.out.println(element3.getTextContent());
    }}

}
```

}

данные:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product name="eee">
        <id>p01</id>
        <name>Product1</name>
        <price>100</price>
    </product>
    <product name="pp">
        <id>p02</id>
        <name>Product2</name>
        <price>200</price>
    </product>
    <product name="rr">
        <id>p03</id>
        <name>Product3</name>
        <price>300</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не работает? Как нам запустить это у себя и убедиться, что и правда не работает?

Comment: @andreymal изменил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из ошибок в том что для атрибута не нужно брать item по i, всегда будет 0.

```
nl2.item(i).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Второе вы не правильно формируете `expression`, для нахождения имени нужно использовать не `nl2.item(i).getAttributes()`, а `nl2.item(i).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeName()`

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно найти продукт с определенным именем, ниже код как я это вижу

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

public class Main {

    private static final String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                                      "<products>\n" +
                                      "    <product name=\"eee\">\n" +
                                      "        <id>p01</id>\n" +
                                      "        <name>Product1</name>\n" +
                                      "        <price>100</price>\n" +
                                      "    </product>\n" +
                                      "    <product name=\"pp\">\n" +
                                      "        <id>p02</id>\n" +
                                      "        <name>Product2</name>\n" +
                                      "        <price>200</price>\n" +
                                      "    </product>\n" +
                                      "    <product name=\"rr\">\n" +
                                      "        <id>p03</id>\n" +
                                      "        <name>Product3</name>\n" +
                                      "        <price>300</price>\n" +
                                      "    </product>\n" +
                                      "</products>";


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Введите имя продукта:");
        String productName = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        ProductXmlSearcher searcher = new ProductXmlSearcher(getDocument());
        Element product = searcher.getProductByName(productName);

        if (Objects.nonNull(product)) {
            System.out.println(product.getNodeName());
            System.out.println(product.getTextContent());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Продукт не найден для:" + productName);
        }


    }

    private static Document getDocument() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        return db.parse(is);
    }

    static class ProductXmlSearcher {
        private final Document document;
        private final XPath xPath;

        ProductXmlSearcher(Document document) {
            this.document = document;
            this.xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        }

        public Element getProductByName(String productName) {
            String expression = "//products/*[@name='" + productName + "']";
            try {
                XPathExpression compiledXPath = xPath.compile(expression);
                return (Element) compiledXPath.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Element not found for expression: " + expression, e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Не совсем надо чтоб не только по name искало по любым атрибутам которые добавлет пользователь. Ну нам скзали зделать типа максимально автоматизированую прогу. Которая подстраивалсь под любые изменения файла

Comment: Ну вот у меня там же два %s одно это назване атрибута второе его значение

Comment: Как-бы максимальная автоматизация

Comment: Если для любого атрибута то замените на * например:
String expression = "//products/*[@*='" + productName + "']";
или вводите имя аттрибута с консоли и передовайте параметром

Comment: блин а я мучался а там можно просто звездочку поставить

Comment: рад что вам помогло

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: отметьте плз тогда ответ как правильный

Comment: отметил же прям когда вы первый раз написали

Comment: @ Ihar Hulevich А понял. Я просто не знал что то за галочка.

Comment: извиняюсь не знал как это делается